# IE proxy settings reset themselves

Tags: windows-7, proxy, internet-explorer

I cannot successfully save proxy settings for my Windows 7 computer.  I already [reset my IE](https://superuser.com/a/576732), it did not help.  I ran process monitor on my computer after entering the proxy settings and found that the `inetcpl.cpl` process (the "Internet Properties" dialog) sets the proxy like I specify and then it *resets the same information*.

Here's the log.

```
"Time of Day","Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail"
"11:28:17.8879567 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegSetValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable","SUCCESS","Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 1"
"11:28:17.8879868 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegSetValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer","SUCCESS","Type: REG_SZ, Length: 34, Data: 192.168.1.2:8888"
"11:28:17.8880194 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegDeleteValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride","ACCESS DENIED",""
"11:28:17.8885601 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyHttp1.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144"
"11:28:17.8887643 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable","SUCCESS","Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 0"
"11:28:17.8887813 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144"
"11:28:17.8887979 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegQueryValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144"
"11:28:17.8891380 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegSetValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable","SUCCESS","Type: REG_DWORD, Length: 4, Data: 0"
"11:28:17.8891642 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegDeleteValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyServer","ACCESS DENIED",""
"11:28:17.8891918 AM","rundll32.exe","2264","RegDeleteValue","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyOverride","ACCESS DENIED",""
```

Answer (score 0):

**My 1st Question** From you would be,

is your machine part of Corporate Network?

Proxy settings could be automatically removed by group policies.

**My 2nd Question would be**

Are you running any network capture software while testing the same ?

For example if you are using Fiddler ,as soon as you turn it on it will change the proxy and 
redirect all traffic through another proxy handled by fiddler.

Please let me know above info for more help.